# SKTextureAtlas textureNamed not automatically finding texture suffixes @3x in XCode 6 GM Seed

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, iphone-6-plus

I had NSLog my textureAtlas that it has all my @3x.PNG loaded but it returns missing texture by calling textureNamed:

```
#define TEXT_MAINMENU @"mainmenu"
SKTextureAtlas *textureAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"414x736"];
NSLog(@"atlas: %@", textureAtlas);
SKTexture *_MAINMENU = [textureAtlas textureNamed:TEXT_MAINMENU];
NSLog(@"texture from skatlas: %@", _MAINMENU);
```

The output is here:

> atlas:  '414x736' 83 textures: (
>       " 'mainmenu@3x.png' (279 x 279)",
>       " 'winreplay@3x.png' (873 x 131)",
>       " 'bonus128@3x.png' (279 x 279)",
>       " 'maincake128@3x.png' (279 x 279)",
>       " 'bonus512@3x.png' (279 x 279)", ........
>
> texture from skatlas:  'MissingResource.png' (128 x 128)

However, where I get texture by textureWithImageNamed (not by SKTextureAtlas textureNamed) and it fallbacks to me the @1x.PNG?

```
SKTexture *_MAINMENU2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:TEXT_MAINMENU];
NSLog(@"texture from sktexture: %@",_MAINMENU2);
```

The output is here:

> texture from sktexture:  'mainmenu' (90 x 90)

Of course I also had @1x @2x PNG for the same code that runs well, and I am wondering why my textureAtlas/texture not automatically find my @3x.PNG? Is there something wrong with me and how to fix it?

Comment: what is 'textureAtlas' in this context? First line seems to be missing something, there are two opening but three closing brackets.

Comment: yeah doesnt seem to work for me either =/  a few things are still pretty broken in the final version

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting the "MissingResource" message because you are not accessing your texture atlas with a valid key. When you manually create a texture atlas you usually use the `atlasWithDictionary:` like so:

```
NSDictionary *testDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"mine@1x.png", @"mine64", @"mine@2x.png", @"mine128", @"mine@3x.png", @"mine256", nil];

SKTextureAtlas *testAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasWithDictionary:testDictionary];
```

mine64 is a 64x64 png, mine128 is a 128x128 png and mine256 is a 256x256 png. Obviously you need unique keys for the dictionary so you have to manually code what image size you want, depending on iPhone model, when it's time to place the image like so:

```
SKSpriteNode *myNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[testAtlas textureNamed:@"mine256"]];
```

BUT, according to the latest Apple SKTextureAtlas docs:

> Discussion
>   Normally, Xcode creates texture atlases at compile time from the image files included in your project. These atlases are compiled and installed inside the app bundle. However, sometimes the assets needed to create a texture atlas are not available at compile time. For example, those assets might be procedurally generated or downloaded from the network. However, you still want the benefit of texture atlases to reduce the number of state changes required in the hardware. You can use this method to generate an atlas at runtime. This is a potentially expensive operation best performed when your game loop is not running.

The way I understand it is that Xcode will auto generate all required texture atlases itself. With that in mind, adding these 3 images to the project: mine@1x.png, mine@2x.png, mine@3x.png and then using:

```
SKSpriteNode *myNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"mine.png"];
```

will result in the right image being used based on screen resolution.

An alternative is for you to use an app like [TexturePacker](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) to create your own texture atlases and add them to your project.